# Arzela-Ascoli generalisation uniform or pointwise convergence?

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, metric-spaces, uniform-convergence, arzela-ascoli

I am a bit confused because the classical Arzela-Ascoli gives uniform convergence  of a sequence (taking a sub-sequence if necessary) of functions. However the more general results seem to require pointwise convergence first.

Given a compact Hausdorff metric space $X$ and a complete metric space $Y$, and sequence of continuous functions $f_n:X\to Y$. I wonder if anyone has a reference for Arzela-Ascoli in this particular case to show that $f_n$ converges uniformly to some $f$ in the metric of $Y$ (taking sub-sequence if necessary). Where we don't a-priori have pointwise convergence.

Note : Proposition 3.3.1 of the book (Gradient Flows in Metric Spaces by Ambrosio, picture below) provides a Arzela-Ascoli pointwise convergence result, it seems like combining this with the results found on the wiki https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arzel%C3%A0%E2%80%93Ascoli_theorem#Generalizations we get uniform convergence. I'm finding it hard to reconcile Proposition 3.3.1 with the wikipedia. [image]

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich didn't realise it would require download thought it was a read online. Its the first link that appears when googling the name of the book so I assumed it was... How can you tell if something like that is legal? Sorry!

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich is this any better?

Comment: It would be much better if you explained the notation. What is $\sigma$; what does "sequentially compact wrt to $\sigma$" mean; what is that thing that looks like the letter often used for the Schwarz space?